# Automatically send a PDF (generated through browser's print dialog) to a server

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am using bindery.js to generate a PDF of a web page which needs to be sent to a server through http request. Bindery generates the PDF through the browser's print dialog using window.print() function.

My problem is that I need to send this generated PDF automatically to the server (instead of downloading locally and then uploading the pdf).

I have tried different client-side as well as server-side pdf generating libraries (html2pdf, pdfdom, tcpdf etc) but those do not seem to render the pdf correctly (as my page contains large number of svg images). Is there a way to send the PDF generated through browser's print dialog to the server automatically after being generated?

Comment: In short: no.  The print dialog is not part of the DOM / javascript domain so js has no access to this.

Comment: Np, not really. Printing as a PDF, will open the "Save as" dialog, so that the user can specify the location & name under which the file should be saved. You have no way of setting those upfront. And even if you did, and therefor already knew the location where it is stored on the client - normal JavaScript running in a website context won't be able to _access_ it from that location either. That part also needs active user participation again (selecting the file via a file input field.)

Comment: Did you try: `view: Bindery.View.PREVIEW`?  Perhaps you could have it create the preview then use *another* js html-to-pdf library to convert the preview to a pdf?   Sounds overly complicated.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I tried it with multiple libraries but none of them seem to be able to render svg images properly. Only parts of the images are rendered when pdf is generated.

Comment: Send the resolved HTML to a server, generate the PDF there, send it back (dynamically create a link to it) if you wish the user to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used html2pdf to pdf convert the preview generated by bindery.js the images of the pdf were not being rendered properly. It seems that html2pdf was not able to render svg images properly. I converted the svg images to png and now are rendered properly on the pdf and was able to send this pdf to the server.