# svg images are ignored when using html2canvas and jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

html2canvas and jdpdf is ignoring the svg images when i download

```
    document.getElementById("download")
.addEventListener("click", () => {


  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
    return function(type, attribs) {
      attribs = attribs || {};
      attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
      return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
    };
  }(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
    

    const mapDownload = this.document.getElementById("mapDownload");
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2, useCORS: true, },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(mapDownload).set(opt).save();
})
```

Above is the snippet. I am i missing anything here to make that work ?

Webpage with map marker
[image: Webpage with map marker]

PDF downloaded
[image]

Comment: May be this  is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493988/error-loading-svg-data-with-html2canvas-and-jspdf

Comment: Answer seems unrelated to the question, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75852807/2181514) is that they had to convert svg's to png's first.